# How to hand a string with spaces as single parameter?

Tags: batch-file

How can I hand a string that contains whitespaces as single paramter?

```
SET STRING=this is my teststring
call .\newFile.cmd %STRING%

newFile.cmd:
ECHO %1% //gives: "this"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with

```
SET STRING=this is my teststring
call .\newFile.cmd "%STRING%"

newFile.cmd:
ECHO %~1
```

The `%~1` removes surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1 - Use quotes around the string

`SET STRING="this is my teststring"`

2 - Escape the spaces

`SET STRING=this\ is\ my\ teststring`

Comment: The second sample is wrong, the backslash has no special meaning in batch.